# Issue with assigning value to PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to change the value of a tensor to a different tensor but when I perform the assignment, the tensor stores 0 instead of the assigned value. A sample of my code causing the issue is found below:

```
import torch
def normalize(x, x_min, x_max):
       return x/(x_max - x_min)

x_min = torch.tensor([-5,  0])
x_max = torch.tensor([10, 15])

old = torch.tensor([[-3,-3],[3,3]])
for i in range(old.shape[0]):
    old[i] = normalize(old[i], x_min, x_max)
print(old)
```

Comment: Check the `dtype`. `torch.int64` will convert float values to int.

Comment: BTW, no need to loop: `old / (x_max - x_min)` does the same.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That seems to have fixed the issue, thanks!